# How change the background of all activities?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I will also try this :

```
public Button button;  
public View background;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_option);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.color);
    background = findViewById(R.id.colorBackg);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int colorCreat = Color.rgb(255, 255, 255);
            background.setBackgroundColor(colorCreat);
        }
    });

}
```

It works but when I change the activity the color resets. How I can change the color of all background permanently ? Thanks.

Comment: edit the background variable in your styles.xml file.

Comment: apply a theme that has a windowbackground to all activities

Answer (score 3):

Create a style under styles.xml in res directory of your project

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

   <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="app_theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The above theme can then be applied to you application element in manifest like this

```
<application
 android:theme="@style/Theme.Activity.Default"/>
```

So this implies all the activity will inherit the above style declared in Application tag, unless any individual Activity overrides it specifying some other style.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks ! Can I add button to change color with this method ?

Comment: @Jack a good design will be to have a preferences that change the color value (instead of a button)

Comment: @vincrichaud if I understand I must use SharedPreferences to change color of background dynamically ?

Comment: @Jack I meant [App Settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings). It's been a time since I last implement this so I don't remember well how it works, have a look to the guide. It was a hint about architecture, it's better to define the color in a Setting activity, and then every activity will get the color from the settings, than having a button in each activity to define the background. (Note: this is not always true if each activty background is intended to be different, it could be simpler to have a button in each...)

Comment: @vincrichaud I made a Setting Activity with 2 buttons. One to change the color of background to white and the other to change the color to black. So I can't use styles.xml. When I push a color the background of all activity must be change. But I don't know how. I search a lot of time on several website. Ihave seen nothing. I have to use buttons for my project

Answer (score 0):

As already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51137244/5914654) by [Mayank Bhatnagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5607107/mayank-bhatnagar), you should create an style inside the styles.xml file. See [the guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) for detailed implementation.

---

If you want to be able to dynamically change the theme, I recommend you to use a [Settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) to define which them to use. And then in your activities to listen to preference change.

First create a Listener to preference change, that will react to style change.

```
public class StylePreferenceChangeListener implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    //String constant used as ID to the style preference (used here and in SettingActivity)
    public static String PREFERENCE_STYLE_ID = "preference.style";

    //The activity that we want to modify style
    private Activity activity;

    public StylePreferenceChangeListener(Activity activity) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    // listener implementation
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        if(PREFERENCE_STYLE_ID.equals(key)) {
            int newStyleId = prefs.getInt(key, R.style.default_style);
            activity.getTheme.applyStyle(newStyleId, true);
    }

}
```

And in your activity, create an instance of this Listener. And register/unregister it inside onResume()/onPause().

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

    //Our listener reference
    StylePreferenceChangeListener myListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate();
        setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
        //create instance now so we are sure the activity exist
        myListener = new StylePreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //register our listener
        getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(myListener);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //unregister our listener
        getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(myListener);
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //The activity is meant to be destroy, makes no sense to keep our listener
        //Drop his reference to allow garbage collecting
        myListener = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh thank a lot. I try and I can change the color of one activity. Now I will try to other activities.

Comment: @Jack this need to be tested because I couldn't I do not have Android Studio currently. But I think it's the way to do.

Comment: I will try your code. It's works for me thanks. Just one last question that has nothing to do with the subject. If I use MVP can I call an activity in my presenter ? Does it respect the MVP?

Comment: Example : public void test(Activity activity) {
       activity...
    }